# How can I use FirestorePagingAdapter for a RecyclerView in NestedScrollView

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview, firebaseui, android-nestedscrollview

I am using FirestorePagingAdapter to fetch my documents from Firestore. Everything is perfect but The "Load more" is happening automatically without getting to the bottom of the list. This is causing a janky behaviour.

I have placed my RecyclerView(Height: wrap content) in a NestedScrollView(Height: match-parent) which is the content of my main scrolling activity layout.

Is there a way to load more items only when I scroll to the last item.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".NewLookCode.activities.MainScrollingActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main_scrolling">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_transporters"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:visibility="visible" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

```
 val baseQuery = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("partners")
    val config = PagedList.Config.Builder()
            .setEnablePlaceholders(true)
            .setPrefetchDistance(2)
            .setPageSize(6)
            .build()

    val options = FirestorePagingOptions.Builder<PartnerInfoPojo>()
            .setLifecycleOwner(this)
            .setQuery(baseQuery, config, PartnerInfoPojo::class.java)
            .build()
    adapter = object:FirestorePagingAdapter<PartnerInfoPojo, PartnersViewHolder>(options) {
        @NonNull
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull parent: ViewGroup, viewType:Int):PartnersViewHolder {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_new_transporter, parent, false)
            return PartnersViewHolder(view)
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(@NonNull holder:PartnersViewHolder,
                                      position:Int,
                                      @NonNull model:PartnerInfoPojo) {
                holder.mCompany.text = model.getmCompanyName()

            if(model!=null){
                if(model.getmCompanyAdderss()!=null)
                    holder.mAddress.text = model.getmCompanyAdderss().city
            }


        }

    }

    rv_transporters.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    rv_transporters.adapter = adapter
```

Comment: Add the code that you have tried @ShubhamSardar

Comment: @Raj I have added the code. Please tell if you can help.